# Is it a bug of os.path.abspath to translate '~/path'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.path

See below:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath('~/gitlab')
'/home/swift/gitlab/swift_test_code/swift/core/~/gitlab'
>>> os.path.expanduser('~/gitlab')
'/home/swift/gitlab'
```

Does anyone know why abspath doesn't expand `~` as the home directory? It's tricky to call expand before calling abspath.

Comment: No, it's not a bug - if you want `~` expanded to the user directory, use `expanduser`; [`abspath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) uses the current directory, it *"is equivalent to calling ... `normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))`."*